# How do i migrate a model containing an ImageField from django-imagekit using django-south?

Tags: django, imagekit, django-south, custom-fields, django-models

I find this documentation extremely confusing:
http://south.aeracode.org/docs/customfields.html

If someone could walk me through this or at least give a full example, I would be very grateful.

Comment: I don't see any such ImageField in [django-imagekit](http://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/)'s source.  Could you clarify, maybe point to a specific file / line number?

Comment: original_image = models.ImageField(upload_to='photos') as seen on http://bitbucket.org/jdriscoll/django-imagekit/wiki/Home

Comment: Sounds like you're using the standard django.db.models.ImageField. Strange that South would have any problems with that.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the time, you just need to do something like this when using a custom field (example using the ImageWithThumbnailsField from sorl.thumbnail):

```
# models.py
from south.modelsinspector import add_introspection_rules

add_introspection_rules([], ["^sorl\.thumbnail\.fields\.ImageWithThumbnailsField"])
```

From the South docs: If your custom field inherits from a core Django field, or another field for which there are already introspection rules, and it doesn’t add any new attributes, then you probably won’t have to add any rules for it, as it will inherit all those from its parents.